# Fetch javascript variable value from a WebBrowser using VB

Tags: javascript, vb.net, variables

I am trying to fetch the value of a javascript variable embedded in the webpage of my webbrowser in VB WinForm.

The following is the javascript from the webpage that gets loaded in my webBrowser in WinForms.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var isJsTrue=0;
            if (typeof(LoadAsync) == 'function'){                   
                LoadAsync();
            }else{
                isJsTrue=1;
            }
            setTimeout(function()       
            }, 5000 ); 
        });
</script>
```

I need to fetch the value of the variable "isJsTrue" in VB form.

Could anyone tell me how this could be done?
Also, is it possible to change the value of the same variable?

Comment: You can't. That variable is within the function passed to `ready` and can't be accessed outside of it.

Comment: If you have access to page source, copy the values into a dom element and read back it from your control like Document.getelementbyId("txtbox").Value in